# Should my jquery code be visible to everyone

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I know I can't hide it. But I just want to be sure that I am doing this thing right.
I have a master view where I render a few partial views:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
...
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Product");}
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Machine");}
```

In **Product & Machine** controller I have other actions and view for simple CRUD operations.
And each index has it's JS code to manipulate view when user try to do some actions.
On the image bellow I display what I can see on my site now when I open it and inspect.
This JS code is visible to everyone and my question is am I exposed to some kind of attack?
On production I will obfuscate *.js files.
And on server side I first check if user can make action (based on current userID).
I just want to know is my approach good or bad.

[image]
[image]

Comment: There's nothing you can do about that I'm afraid.

Comment: If you know your javascript code will expose a vulnerability, why not just fix that vulnerability itself?

Comment: Bottom line is validate EVERYTHING on the server side. When a user attempts to change a record, validate that that user has access to that record. Don't assume the request came from a normal page action.

Comment: I second @BradM. If your protection is hoping that attackers do not find a vulnerability, you basically have "Security through obscurity": en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you are validating the request on server side, you shouldn't worry about it. There is no way to hide JavaScript since you have to send it to the client. Obfuscation can be reversed. You should worry  about [CSRF attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) though. Probably nobody will bother to reverse engineer your JavaScript code. Once an attacker finds a way to make a valid request to your action, they will try to tamper the data or trick other people to make requests they are not aware of.

Comment: This is solid advice. You should only really worry about embedding URLs into client side code if you are doing things like interpreting querystrings in JavaScript; basically giving someone an "in" to manipulating your code on a mass scale.